# Nasa binary files in Java

Tags: java, file-io, binary

I have file with binary data. This is specification:

> The SRTM data files have names like "N34W119.hgt". What do the
>   letters and numbers refer to, and what is ".hgt" format?
>
> Each data file covers a one-degree-of-latitude by one-degree-of-longitude block of Earth's surface. The first seven
>   characters indicate the southwest corner of the block, with N, S, E,
>   and W referring to north, south, east, and west. Thus, the
>   "N34W119.hgt" file covers latitudes 34 to 35 North and longitudes
>   118-119 West (this file includes downtown Los Angeles, California).
>   The filename extension ".hgt" simply stands for the word "height",
>   meaning elevation. It is NOT a format type. These files are in "raw"
>   format (no headers and not compressed), 16-bit signed integers,
>   elevation measured in meters above sea level, in a "geographic"
>   (latitude and longitude array) projection, with data voids indicated
>   by -32768. International 3-arc-second files have 1201 columns and 1201
>   rows of data, with a total filesize of 2,884,802 bytes ( = 1201 x 1201
>   x 2). United States 1-arc-second files have 3601 columns and 3601 rows
>   of data, with a total filesize of 25,934,402 bytes ( = 3601 x 3601 x
>   2). For more information read the text file "SRTM_Topo.txt" at
>   http://edcftp.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/srtm/Readme.html

Anyone can help me how I can read this file in java? It is possible to read this file to array, because I need to do some operations on elements from this file?

Comment: Either you have to find a library that reads this particular format or you need to parse that yourself. I.e. read the file contents and parse those characters, ints and give meaning to them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would read the entire file into a ShortBuffer (so you choose the endianess)

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) fc.size());
while (bb.remaining() > 0) fc.read(bb);
fc.close();
bb.flip();
// choose the right endianness
ShortBuffer sb = bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
```

Comment: Great. I have another question. I need read this data in other order ie. last element should be first, one before last shold be second etc. How I can do this?

Comment: You can use `ShortBuffer.get(int position)` to access the `short` values in any order.